# Vim registers fast pasting with :reg view

Tags: register

I want to have fast pasting while having `:reg` view. I have remapping:

`:noremap <C-r><C-r> <ESC>:reg<CR>`

While i am in this mode I want to to have single keystroke(buffer name) option like: ", 1, 2, 3, *, #, /, etc.. to paste register.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
:nnoremap <C-r><C-r> :reg<CR>:let regname = input("Register? ") \| exe 'norm "' . regname . 'p'<CR>
```

You'll see the `:reg` output and then a prompt. At the prompt enter the register (`#`, `a`, `@`, etc.) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The contents of the selected register will be `p`asted right after the current position of the cursor.

This is adapted from [an answer I gave to a similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18166/11054) about acting on the output of the `[I` command.

Fortunately, `:reg` enters the same general "what now?" prompt as `[I` does. That prompt allows `:` as a response and that puts us on the regular command line without dismissing the previous command's output. From there it's just a matter of displaying a prompt and then building a `:normal` command that pastes whatever register the user entered.

---

**Update:** Sounds like OP is interested in a variation that doesn't require hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should do it:

```
:nnoremap <C-r><C-r> :reg<CR>:echom "Register? "\|let n=nr2char(getchar())\|exe 'norm "'.n.'p'\|redraw<CR>
```

Besides using `nr2char(getchar())` to get the register name I tacked a `:redraw` onto the end to eliminate the *Press Enter or type command to continue* prompt that blocks immediate return to Normal mode.

(FYI it's also shortened/compressed a bit compared to the first one.)

Comment: that is a very good answer. :) One remark: because register is a single character, process can be optimize by elimination of  enter hittig at the end if it is possible...

Comment: that's nice solution. Do you know how to force Vim to display `:reg` window in vertical split?

Comment: I'm not aware of any native way to do that. Windows hold buffers while the `:reg` output is an extension of the command line and that's "global"; it'll display in the same place regardless of what window/buffer is current. I could probably make something like that work with a fair amount of scripting. I'm not volunteering, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I’ve not used it myself, but [peekaboo](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo) provides a sort of HUD for pasting.

It’s not a “quick-paste” as you describe but may solve the same problem.

Comment: Actually it is quite fast in insert mode: <C-r> and register number hit